# Prove $\lim_ \limits{x\to x_0}{r_n(x)\over (x-x_0)^n}=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f: I \to \Bbb{R}$ be differentiable $n$ times at $x_0\in I$, and let $r_n(x)$ be the remainder of order $n$ that in the Taylor formula of $f$ around $x_0$. Prove $\lim_
\limits{x\to x_0}{r_n(x)\over (x-x_0)^n}=0$. Just so there are no misunderstanding, in the Peano theorem we were given, we have $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}{{f^{(j)}(x_0)}\over j!}(x-x_0)^j+\color{red}{o((x-x_0)^n)}$ (As I understood, it is different when you write it.)

I tried this using the remainders by Lagrange and Cauchy but they require $f^{(n+1)}$ which I don't know if exists. Besides, I don't know how to divide absolute value by a regular value and conversely. I would appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Note, 
\begin{eqnarray}
r_n(x)&=&f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k
\end{eqnarray}
and hence, by L'Hopital's Rule, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{r_n(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}&=&\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f^{k}(x_0)}{(k-1)!}(x-x_0)^{k-1}}{n(x-x_0)^{n-1}}\\
&=&\cdots\\
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)-f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)}{n!(x-x_0)}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f^{(n)}(x_0)\right)\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}